# TextInputLayout hint issue when handling FocusChange event

Tags: android-edittext, xamarin.android, android-textinputlayout

My app has a couple of `EditText`s with a `TextInputLayout` wrapped around them. This works fine in most cases, but when I attach a handler to the FocusChange event of the `EditText`, the hint fails to animate.

I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175344) issue on the android forum, but he uses the OnFocusChangeListener. Proxying the call should not be necessary with events, right?

Any ideas on this issue? Is it a bug in the Xamarin android design support NuGet package?

Thanks in advance

**Layout code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtProductCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
        android:hint="Artikelcode" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Fragment code:**

```
public override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();

    txtProductCode.FocusChange += txtProductCode_FocusChange;
     // ...
}

void txtProductCode_FocusChange(object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.HasFocus)
        txtDescription.Text = GetProductDescription();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From this post [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178693) i found my solution for the problem. 
As stated in the post it's kind of a workaround but i think this should work in the new design library version 22.2.1 but for me the problem still persists.

Here is my code based on the mentioned post:

```
        final View.OnFocusChangeListener userNameEtFocusListener = userNameEt.getOnFocusChangeListener();

    userNameEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            userNameEtFocusListener.onFocusChange(v, hasFocus);

            if (!hasFocus){
                userInfoValidator.checkUserNameAvailable(userNameEt.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
```